# combine 2 basic queries to return one result

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using PostgreSQL I have two queries. I want to combine the two queries to return two integer values separated by commas.

```
 SELECT * from newlayerya_1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 

 SELECT * from newlayerya_1 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
```

-- should return for example 141,23

Iv tried some examples I found online but having no joy with it.

```
CREATE FUNCTION test_ret(a integer, b integer) RETURNS RECORD AS $$
DECLARE 
  ret RECORD;
BEGIN
  -- Arbitrary expression to change the first parameter
  --IF LENGTH(a) < LENGTH(b) THEN
     -- SELECT TRUE, a || b, 'a shorter than b' INTO ret;
      SELECT * from newlayerya_1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 INTO ret;
 -- ELSE
    --  SELECT FALSE, b || a INTO ret;
      SELECT * from newlayerya_1 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1 INTO ret;
  --END IF;
RETURN ret;
END;$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Use union among tables

Comment: Removed the MySQL tag since you're not using it.

Comment: You're overcomplicating it.  Two queries UNIONed together, or two subqueries to return them as columns, will allow better execution plans, simpler code, etc, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    (SELECT id from newlayerya_1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1),
    (SELECT id from newlayerya_1 ORDER BY id  ASC LIMIT 1)
```

Should avoid any anti-patterns, such as casting integers as strings.

Or, even simpler...

```
SELECT
    MAX(ID), MIN(ID)
FROM
    newlayera_1
```

Comment: ERROR:  subquery must return only one column

Comment: Oops, copy and paste error ;)  Need to select just ID or appropriate column.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT id from newlayerya_1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 
UNION
SELECT id from newlayerya_1 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
```

Remember number of field on both query should be same.

Answer (score 0):

The [UNION](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/queries-union.html) keyword does this; as long as both queries return the same columns (which yours does).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id ASC) as rnum1, 
       row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id DESC) as rnum2
from newlayerya_1
where STUFF = 'STUFF'
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM yourdatabase
WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM yourdatabase) or
ID = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM yourdatabase);
```